# Get text from listview onclick (Android)

Tags: android, listview

I am creating lists in my android app and would like to capture the text of the list item that is clicked but I want to do it in a seperate function so I only have to write the code once. And I want to be able to compare the string to another sting.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  OnItemClickListener() set to your list and overwrite

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

then get you text either from item itself or from the view.

Comment: Thanks, I got that to work but, I cant compare it for some reason. It makes me use CharSequence as a type instead of String and when I compare it to another string it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: There is bunch of methods on the String object to compare it with CharSequence.  and there is toString on cs as well. How you're getting value ( code ) ?

Comment: Ok I figured it out, actually SE figured it out for me. I was using == to compare. I am such a newb at this.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704956/strings-dont-seem-to-be-equal-in-java-on-android-even-though-they-print-the-sam